# ServiceContractGenerator should not generate XmlElementAttribute(Order= )

Tags: .net, wcf

I use ServiceContractGenerator to generate client proxies (at design-time, but not with the Add Service Reference in VS).
Work fine, but it generates an XmlElementAttribute(Order = ) on every property in my data classes.
Thus the order of the properties is fixed. If something in the ordering on the server changes, I need to regenerate the clientside. 
Any idea how to prevent ServiceContractGenerator from generating the XmlElementAttribute ?

Thanks, Jaap

Comment: Seems to be a difficult question ;-)

Comment: I don't know the answer, but you might want to gain more reputation and start a bounty? Also, maybe you should try to separate in paragraphs, add links (ServiceContractGenerator) and fomatting?